# how to sum up two accumulators output in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am able to increment accumulator(totalMatchedCitationsCount totalNumUnMatchedCitationsCount) but unable to add two accumulator outputs.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Citing Matching")
val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
  
val totalNumUnMatchedCitationsCount = sc.accumulator(0, "Total_number_of_unmatched_citations")
val totalMatchedCitationsCount = sc.accumulator(0, "Total_matched_citations")
val totalNumCitationsCount = sc.accumulator(0, "Total_number_of_citations")

totalMatchedCitationsCount.add(1)
totalNumUnMatchedCitationsCount.add(1)
```

However unable to add above two accumulators and stores in 3rd accumulators(totalNumCitationsCount ). Below codes getting compilation, error, trying to add two accumulators outputs
totalNumCitationsCount = totalMatchedCitationsCount + totalNumUnMatchedCitationsCount

Answer (score 0):

Add the values to the accumulator, not the accumulator itself.

```
totalNumCitationsCount.add(
    totalMatchedCitationsCount.value + totalNumUnMatchedCitationsCount.value)
```